# Why is object-fit not working with max-height container?

Tags: css, height

I'm trying to place a video into a container which has 100% `width` and auto `height` respecting the aspect ratio but with `max-height` set. I want the video to fill the entire container even if the sides are cropped **and to be centered both horizontally and vertically**.

I'm using `fit-object` property but apparently it doesn't work with `max-height`.

I'll simplify it with an image. The result should be the same.

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now, if I add to `div` style `height: 100px`, it works. If I write `max-height: 100px`, it doesn't. Is this expected behaviour? If so, what can I do to make it work?

Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1r4mLvLq/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`height: 100%;` works only if an ancestor element has an explicit height set.

You can accomplish that by adding this CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1r4mLvLq/1/)

Comment: Gosh. Thanks. I had height: 100% on all ancestors, except <html>. I didn't realize that.